# plural and the use of it

Tags: grammatical-number

consider the following sentence:

Once all data are collected, it is exported as ...

I am not sure whether it is correct to use the word 'it' in this context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not write it like that. You are confusing the count defintion of *data* and the non-count definition.

Either:

> Once all data are collected, they are exported ...

Or:

> Once the data is collected, it is exported ...

Don't mix them up.

Comment: Right, that's why I was asking for :) I use data as plural so I will go for they are exported. thanks a lot